# Despite utf8 encoding some characters fail to be recognized

Tags: python, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape an RSS with a news title like this:

```xml
<title>Photo of iceberg that is believed to have sunk Titanic sold at auction for £21,000 alongside &amp;#039;world&amp;#039;s most valuable biscuit&amp;#039;</title>
```

This is effectively how I'm using Beautiful Soup to scrape it:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
start = soup.findAll('item')
for i in start:
    news, is_created = News.create_or_update(news_id,                                                  
    head_line=i.title.text.encode('utf-8').strip(),
    ...)
```

However despite this effort the title remains like this:

```
Photo of iceberg that is believed to have sunk Titanic sold at auction for \xa321,000 alongside &#039;world&#039;s most valuable biscuit&#039;
```

Would it be easier just to convert these special characters into ASCII character?

Comment: Good you found it. Why didn't the `html` library work? Do you still need help?

Comment: @Jongware sure. done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example you provide, this works for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html

xml='<title>Photo of iceberg that is believed to have sunk Titanic sold at auction for £21,000 alongside &amp;#039;world&amp;#039;s most valuable biscuit&amp;#039;</title>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')
print(html.unescape(soup.get_text()))
```

`html.unescape` handles the HTML entities. If Beautiful Soup is not handling the pound sign correctly, you may need to specify the encoding when creating the `BeautifulSoup` object, e.g.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml", from_encoding='latin-1')
```

Comment: Does it mean the way I read the title is wrong? `i.title.text.encode('utf-8')`  When I try this unit tests:`self.assertEquals(expected.head_line.decode('utf-8'), u" ... ")` it fails with the message: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 75-76: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: It's hard to tell because you only posted part of your code. It's easier to work with a minimal example that displays your problem, you might want to update your question with that. I can tell you that the code I posted works as it is written.

Comment: the reason it works for you is because you have decoded the XML as html.  I think I need to do something similar.  Please see updated post.

Answer (score 1):

I finally believe to have found the problem.  These characters above are escaped HTML inside an XML. What a mess. If you look at Independent's [RSS](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/rss) most titles are affected like that.

So this is not an UTF8 problem.  How can I encode any html characters in my title above before converting to to UTF8?

```
head_line=i.title.text.encode('utf-8').strip(),
```

I solved it by unescaping the title with HTMLParser and then encoding it with UTF8. Marco's answer did essentially the same. But the `html` library didn't work for me.

```
head_line=HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(i.title.text).encode('utf-8').strip(),
```

I don't recommend using `from_encoding='latin-1'` as it causes other problems. The solution with `unescaping` and `encode('utf-8')` is enough to decode the £ into `\xa3`, which is proper Unicode chars.