# UTF8 doesn't get displayed in UILabel

Tags: ios, json, utf-8

I have a headline coming in like this: `@"This is what taxi drivers know that you don&#039;t"`

Is `&#039;` the correct UTF8 representation of an apostrophe? If thats the case then the JSON parser is working correctly and its the UILabel that doesn't display the UTF8 correctly.

```
if ([headline containsString:@"taxi"] == YES) {            
     news.headLine = [parsedNews objectForKey:@"head_line"];
}
```

At this breakpoint, I'm seeing the given headline above, if you think the UTF8 representation is wrong, I can post the JSON parser code afterwards.

Comment: Looks like HTML encoding. You don't need to do anything special for `'`. What's in the raw JSON?

Comment: As wain said. You don't need to anything for '. Just write it as it is in code.

Comment: Using tool here: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Decode.aspx decodes the text to '

Comment: It's possible the OP doesn't have any control over the encoding of the JSON from the server.  In that case he will have to perform HTML string decoding manually.

Comment: Thanks to all of you I was able to understand the problem was the HTML characters inside the XML tag.  It is dirty data from Independent's rss.  I don't understand why they use HTML encoding inside XML.  Fortunately I have control over the server and I have fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457951/despite-utf8-encoding-some-characters-fail-to-be-recognized/  Maybe we could solve this challenge also on iOS part, assuming the person didn't have control over the encoding of JSON?  Otherwise feel free to add an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: OK for XML the HTML escaping **is** required.  You didn't mention XML in your question.

Comment: @trojanfoe Would you elaborate please why raw data inside XML tags requires HTML encoding in first place? The two are different formats to represent data and have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` -> Decode to UTF8 `NSData` -> `NSAttributedString` -> `NSString`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *string = @"This is what taxi drivers know that you don&#039;t";
    NSString *parsed = [self urlDecodeString:string usingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"parsed: %@", parsed);
    // parsed: This is what taxi drivers know that you don't
}

- (NSString *)urlDecodeString:(NSString *)string usingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
    NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(encoding)};
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:encoding];
    NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:options documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    return [attString string];
}
```